# Command Prompt Error 'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: batch-file, command-line, msp430, iar

I am trying to run the following batch command. The command has been extracted from the IDE so is confirmed working. Getting the error mentioned below.

I have tried a few variations with double quotes but they haven't worked. 
Even on powershell it has the same message.

```
C:\Program Files\IAR Systems\Embedded Workbench 7.0\430\bin\icc430.exe F:\CP001\source\Meter\Main.c -D Hardware_P20E -D Calibration_code -D _Optical -D _Configuration_TS0382 -o F:\CP001\Temp\C20EO\Obj\ --no_cse --no_unroll --no_inline --no_code_motion --no_tbaa --debug -D__MSP430F425 -e --double=32 --dlib_config C:\Program Files\IAR Systems\Embedded Workbench 7.0\430\lib\dlib\dl430fn.h -Ol --multiplier=16 --segment __data16=DATA16 --segment __data20=DATA20
```

[image: Command Prompt]

Update:

Trying the solution with quotes confuses the compiler in some way

[image]

Comment: You need to put the command in double quotes `"`, or the command prompt will think `C:\Program` is the program to run and the rest are arguments to it.

Comment: Even double quotes are not working

Answer (score 58):

If a directory has spaces in, put quotes around it. This includes the program you're calling, not just the arguments

```
"C:\Program Files\IAR Systems\Embedded Workbench 7.0\430\bin\icc430.exe" "F:\CP001\source\Meter\Main.c" -D Hardware_P20E -D Calibration_code -D _Optical -D _Configuration_TS0382 -o "F:\CP001\Temp\C20EO\Obj\" --no_cse --no_unroll --no_inline --no_code_motion --no_tbaa --debug -D__MSP430F425 -e --double=32 --dlib_config "C:\Program Files\IAR Systems\Embedded Workbench 7.0\430\lib\dlib\dl430fn.h" -Ol --multiplier=16 --segment __data16=DATA16 --segment __data20=DATA20
```

Comment: +1 yes and also parameters with spaces must be quoted (like argument for --dlib_config).

Comment: I tried your solutions. It confuses the compiler somehow. I have posted the new message above.

Answer (score 27):

You just need to keep Program Files in double quote & rest of the command don't need any quote.

```
C:\"Program Files"\IAR Systems\Embedded Workbench 7.0\430\bin\icc430.exe F:\CP00 .....
```

Comment: bad practice. What's with the spaces in `Embedded Workbench 7.0`?

Comment: @dheerajS I did try that

Comment: Sadly this was the only thing that worked for me when trying to create commands within npm's package.json for scripts

Comment: Double quote the full path won't work for me. I am using MSSQL to execute a command, EXEC xp_cmdshell 'C:\"Program Files"\7-Zip\7z.exe a "C:.....

Answer (score 21):

This seems to happen from time to time with programs that are very sensitive to command lines, but one option is to just use the DOS path instead of the Windows path. This means that `C:\Program Files\` would resolve to `C:\PROGRA~1\` and generally avoid any issues with spacing.

To get the short path you can create a quick Batch file that echos the short path:

```
@ECHO OFF
echo %~s1
```

Which is then called as follows:

```
C:\>shortPath.bat "C:\Program Files"
C:\PROGRA~1
```

Comment: I tried setting my PATH variable to use `%ProgramFiles(x86)%` with no luck as I guess it resolved still to the path with spaces - but your solution worked, ended up using "PROGRA~2", thank you so much

Comment: @joshcomley, yes, for `Program Files(x86)` see https://confluence.atlassian.com/doc/setting-the-java_home-variable-in-windows-8895.html: `Progra~1 = 'Program Files'`, `Progra~2 = 'Program Files(x86)'`.

Answer (score 2):

Try putting cd before the file path.

Example:

> C:\Users\user>cd C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.4\bin

Answer (score 1):

> If a directory has spaces in, put quotes around it. This includes the
> program you're calling, not just the arguments
>
> "C:\Program Files\IAR Systems\Embedded Workbench
> 7.0\430\bin\icc430.exe"

Also - SPACES in your `"${workspaceFolder}"` (dir to your project) can confuse the compiler!

At least mine was throwing various errors (like that above, but I had fixed the compiler path), I finally noticed it compiled on PC 1 (dir *without* spaces) and would NOT compile PC 2 (dir *with* spaces).

Actually don't know where to put quotes ("") to make this work because `${workspaceFolder}` or `${fileDirname}` are a [predefined variable](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference) reference in VSC...

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30557264)

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar problem using windows command line for R script, Rscript.exe, which is very sensitive to spaces in the path.  The solution was to create a virtual path to the binary folder using the windows `subst` command.

The following fails: `"C:\Program Files\R\R-3.4.0\bin\Rscript.exe"`

Doing following succeeds:

```
subst Z: "C:\Program Files\R\R-3.4.0"
Z:\bin\Rscript.exe
```

The reason the above-proposed solutions didn't work, evidently, has to do with the Rscript.exe executable's own internal path resolution from its working directory (which has a space in it) rather the windows command line being confused with the space.  So using `~` or `"` to resolve the issue at the command line is moot.  The executable must be called within a path lacking spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the times, the issue is with the paths you have mentioned for 'java home' and 'javac' tags in settings.xml which is present in your .m2 repository and the issue is not with your path variable or Java_Home variable.
If you check and correct the same, you should be able to execute your commands successfully.
- Jaihind

Answer (score 0):

Just go to the folder path and type cmd on it. Then press ENTER
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/04klT.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can go to folder by doing on first line and next line call exe like below.

```
cd 'c:\program files\....'
.\abc.exe --install service
```

Answer (score -1):

I believe James Hunt's answer will solve the problem.

@user3731784: In your new message, the compiler seems to be confused because of the "C:\Program Files\IAR systems\Embedded Workbench 7.0\430\lib\dlib\d1430fn.h" argument. Why are you giving this header file at the middle of other compiler switches?
Please correct this and try again.
Also, it probably is a good idea to give the source file name after all the compiler switches and not at the beginning.

Comment: The command has been picked up from the original IDE. All the switches in it have to be used. Can't ignore anything. Only problem is -O switch because it doesn't have a space after it. Rest works

Answer (score -2):

Go to Start and search for `cmd`. Right click on it, properties then set the `Target` path in quotes. This worked fine for me.