# Run cocos2dx in console

Tags: winapi, cmd, cocos2d-x

I just set up cocos2dx in windows 7. I try to run cocos in cmd, but it doesn't active :

'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

```
    C:\Users\9470m\Documents>cocos run  -s D:\Game\firstGame\firstGame -p win32
Building mode: debug
Building...
Required VS version : [2012, 2013]
running: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\deven
 "D:\Game\firstGame\firstGame\proj.win32\firstgame.sln" /Build "Debug" /Project
game"'

'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Error running command, return code: 1.
```

[image: cocos run not active]
Can you give me an advice.

Comment: ok. thank for your advice

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24904945/command-prompt-error-c-program-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-c

Comment: You show an Image trying to run Cocos2d-x for Win32 I think you should better open your project on Visual Studio