# django-shortcuts command prompt error 'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: django, command-line

Trying to run "django r" command from a django shortcuts https://github.com/jgorset/django-shortcuts

Getting the error  ['C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K1w69.png)

Any ideas how to fix this?
Found some questions with the same error 'C:\Program'  error. Not sure how it could help in my case.
[Command Prompt Error 'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24904945/command-prompt-error-c-program-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-c)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer is based about assumptions but I hope it helps you.

I thinks you have installed Python in a directory like `C:\Programs Files` on you computer. In django-shortcuts, python is called by using `sys.executable` directly in command line ([here](https://github.com/jgorset/django-shortcuts/blob/master/django_shortcuts.py#L71)) and Windows call the first part until space as a executable.
You have different ways to solve this, including :

- use `'"%s"' % sys.executable`
- change `%(python)s` to `"%(python)s"`
- reinstall Python in another directory without space in path ...

Comment: Just tried the second of your proposed ways and it works, server is up and running! Thank you!

Comment: don't forget to validate answer if it's ok for you