# Including a bat with arguments (that launchs a cmd window and adds commands to the path) into another bat

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, windows-10

I have a bat file running a command :

```
C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /E:ON /V:ON /K ""C:\Program Files (x86)\path\to\the\compilers\script.bat" option1 option2"
```

It basically opens a cmd windows for which different commands (intel compilers etc) are already in the path. Then, in this command window I `cd` to a specific location and I use these intel commands as follows :

```
ifort -c -fpp file1.f90
ifort -c -fpp file2.f90
ifort -c -fpp file3.f90
ifort -dll -o libfinal.dll file1.obj file2.obj file3.obj
lib /out:./libfinal.lib file1.obj file2.obj file3.obj
xcopy /s .\libfinal.dll "..\libfinal.dll*" /Y
xcopy /s .\libfinal.lib "..\libfinal.lib*" /Y
```

which compile (with `ifort` intel fortran compiler, but the question doesn't depend on it) libraries and copies them somewhere.

I would to wrap all above into a single bat file doing the whole job. I came up with :

```
call ""C:\Program Files (x86)\path\to\the\compilers\script.bat" option1 option2"
ifort -c -fpp file1.f90
ifort -c -fpp file2.f90
ifort -c -fpp file3.f90
ifort -dll -o libfinal.dll file1.obj file2.obj file3.obj
lib /out:./libfinal.lib file1.obj file2.obj file3.obj
xcopy /s .\libfinal.dll "..\libfinal.dll*" /Y
xcopy /s .\libfinal.lib "..\libfinal.lib*" /Y
```

but running it gives me the following :

```
'""C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command
```

I checked [Command Prompt Error 'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24904945/command-prompt-error-c-program-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-c) but did not succeed in adapting to my situation

*Remark.* `option1` and `option2` don't have spaces or anything requiring quoting, and if I use `call "C:\Program Files (x86)\path\to\the\compilers\script.bat" option1 option2` I have the following error :

```
The input line is too long.
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
```

*Remark.* The true content of the `call` line is :

```
call "C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2017.4.210\windows\bin\ipsxe-comp-vars.bat" intel64 vs2015
```

Comment: Did you try adjusting the quoting, e.g. `Call "C:\Program Files (x86)\path\to\the\compilers\script.bat" option1 option2`. If one or both of the options require quoting you could additionally try doing so thus, `Call "C:\Program Files (x86)\path\to\the\compilers\script.bat" "option1" "option2"`.

Comment: Yes I did (option1 and option2 do not require quoting) and had `The input line is too long. The syntax of the command is incorrect.`

Comment: As we cannot see the true content of your path or your options, my only advice would be to first, `PushD` or `CD` to `"C:\Program Files (x86)\path\to\the\compilers"`, then try `Call script.bat option1 option2`. If you chose `PushD`, then you may wish to add, `PopD`, to the next line after the `Call` line.

Comment: @Compo Updated my question with the true content of the `call` line