# user-config.jam not being interpreted correctly on windows 10

Tags: python, python-3.7, boost-python

I am trying to build the python bindings of libtorrent using boost version 1.63. I've set up my user-config.jam file in my home directory like so:

`using python : 3.7 : C:/Program Files (x86)/Python/Python37-32/python.exe : C:/Program Files (x86)/Python/Python37-32/Include : C:/Program Files (x86)/Python/Python37-32/libs ;`

However when I am running

```
bjam libtorrent-link=static boost-link=static stage_module
```

inside the directory of the python bindings of libtorrent I get the following error:

```
*** argument error
* rule python.init ( version ? : cmd-or-prefix ? : includes * : libraries ? : condition * : extension-suffix ? )
* called with: ( 3.7 : C:/Program Files (x86)/Python/Python37-32/python.exe : C:/Program Files (x86)/Python/Python37-32/Include : C:/Program Files (x86)/Python/Python37-32/libs :  :  :  :  )
* extra argument Files
```

I've done this before on Windows 7 but I haven't experienced anything like that. I've tried all possible ways of formatting it like escaping spaces and parenthesis with a caret `^`, using quotes `'` or double quotes `"`. I've also tried using both forward slash and backslash. Everything yields the same error except for the double quotes:

```
'C:/Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Can anyone point out what I am doing wrong?

Comment: did you check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24904945/command-prompt-error-c-program-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-c)?

Comment: I hadn't, but like the OP of that question mentions, none of the answers there solved the problem. I did a reinstall though and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to reinstall python under C:/Python/37/...

According to the [documentation](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/tools/build/tutorial.html) this should work:

```
using python : 3.7 : "C:/Program Files (x86)/Python/Python37-32/python.exe" :
"C:/Program Files (x86)/Python/Python37-32/Include" : 
"C:/Program Files (x86)/Python/Python37-32/libs" ;
```

but maybe is crashing with something else. Just install python in a directory without spaces if you are working in windows and save a headache.

Comment: This workaround worked but doesn't **answer** the question on why this is happening.