# Pydotplus in Python

Tags: python, ipython, random-forest, pydotplus

I am having a boring day thanks to be not solving a difficult problem, which is about pydotplus in python.

First of all here is my code:

```
from ipywidgets import Image
from io import StringIO
import pydotplus
from sklearn.tree import export_graphviz

d_tree99 = rf.estimators_[99]
dot_data = StringIO()
export_graphviz(d_tree99, feature_names = X.columns,
               out_file = dot_data, filled = True, rounded=True)
graph = pydotplus.graph_from_dot_data(dot_data.getvalue())
Image(value = graph.create_png())
```

I debugged the code in both in Jupyter Notebook, and in Visual Studio Code Python Extension.

And I got the below error in both of them:

> InvocationException
> Traceback (most recent call
> last)
>  in ()
> 9                out_file = dot_data, filled = True, rounded=True)
> 10 graph = pydotplus.graph_from_dot_data(dot_data.getvalue())
> ---> 11 Image(value = graph.create_png())
>
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Anaconda3_64\lib\site-packages\pydotplus\graphviz.py in
> (f, prog)
> 1789             self.**setattr**(
> 1790                 'create_' + frmt,
> -> 1791                 lambda f=frmt, prog=self.prog: self.create(format=f, prog=prog)
> 1792             )
> 1793             f = self.**dict**['create_' + frmt]
>
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Anaconda3_64\lib\site-packages\pydotplus\graphviz.py in
> create(self, prog, format)
> 2024             raise InvocationException(
> 2025                 'Program terminated with status: %d. stderr follows: %s' % (
> -> 2026                     status, stderr_output))
> 2027         elif stderr_output:
> 2028             print(stderr_output)
>
> InvocationException: Program terminated with status: 1. stderr follows: 'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external
> command,
> operable program or batch file.

Could you please inform me why i got this error. And could you please enlighten me about solving this error? This is very important for me.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

If you have a path that contains spaces, you need to quote the path so it gets interpreted correctly by the command line interpreter. This did (for some reason) not happen in your program. I assume that the libraries you are using are not quoting the path correctly.

If that is the case, you have two options:

1. Fix the code in the library, so that it quotes the path correctly
2. Move your source code to a path that doesn't contain spaces

**Related**:
[Command Prompt Error 'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24904945/3579095)

Comment: You say but how will I do this?